# I want to do partition on ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

I have a 1 TB hardisk which is lmv2 and I want to make two partitions of it.

one to normally store stuff. 
and one ntfs where i can store windows 
BUT I get error when i use gpart and this is what it looks like

[image]

When I try to resize the 930 gb drive, it says it's busy as Ubuntu is using it:

Comment: You have to unmount the partitions before editing them.

Comment: how can i unmount if I am using the same drive 
I am much confused

Comment: I don't see an error, but you should really repartition from a liveCD.

Comment: By using a Live system (Either Ubuntu setup DVD/stick or http://gparted.org/livecd.php). And please add the error to your question

Comment: thank you so much but I am using a usb mounted with the windows image

Comment: I have an external hardisk will that help me to mount gparted ?

Comment: also in windows we can partition easliy without any such issues 
why not in ubuntu ?

Comment: I thought you could work on lvm without unmounting - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm @SchezanMansuri - we're not really going to be worried about what you can and can't do in windows. You need to look into managing lvm partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this recently on my laptop.

Are you able to burn a cd?

My suggestion would be to burn a LiveCD of the version of Ubuntu you are running, and reboot onto the CD (not your installed version of ubuntu). When the CD version of Ubuntu has loaded, you will be able to use gparted without your hard drive being mounted which will allow you to partition as you need.

Comment: now i accidently cleared some 500 mb of partition and changed it to ntfc .. now my laptop doesnt even recognizes ubuntu. Just a blank screen on startup saying boot device not found and yes i could burn a cd . But i was that lazy to buy a blank dvd from a store and now i am.regreting

Comment: `ubuntu-vg` <=> `"C:\" with Windows on it`. You cannot repartition that without using a totally different disk to start from.